# ruby debugging user prompt

Tags: ruby, debugging

I need a way to pause the program's flow because there are a lot of print statements that I want to check first. is there a way to do this with ruby, stop the program's flow and continue only if the user has entered yes or stop if it has entered no ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In your code, put `gets`. Then the code will pause at that point until the user inputs <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You don't need to do anything special to terminate because, if you want to, you can just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to chomp off the newline from the return value of `gets`.

```
n, m = 0, 1
repeat = 10

loop do
  repeat.times do
    print "#{m}, "
    n, m = m, n + m
  end
  puts "\nContinue (yes/no)?"
  answer = gets.chomp
  exit if answer == "no"
end
```

Also check out [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry).

```
# test.rb
require 'pry'

class A
  def hello() puts "hello world!" end
end

a = A.new

# start a REPL session
binding.pry

# program resumes here (after pry session)
puts "program resumes here."
```